# Migrating component from 2.5 to 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, development, migration

This documentation: Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 2.5

http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Renamed_events

Really helped me when I migrated my component to 2.5.

I wonder if there is something similar that shows you how to migrate your component from 2.5 to 3.3

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Even the link you have provided in your question does not provide everything single thing that need to be change when migrating an extension. There are always fairly big API differences between each Long Term Release version of Joomla.

For Joomla 3.x, the main thing I tend to look at is the following:

[Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2)

In addition to this, I also look at the latest API site:

http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to make it work, the links @Lodder provided will help massively when dealing with deprecated code.  A bunch of 3.x code was backported while working on 2.5.5, so if you're only supporting that version or later, you could theoretically get a component working on both 2.5 and the 3.x releases with relative ease.  What isn't documented is the layout changes that came with the switch to Bootstrap; you'll need to use the core components as a model for that.

If you're looking to add support for 3.x features (like tags or content history), you'll need to do some more work.  These links will help you integrate support for those features:

- [Using Content History in your Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Content_History_in_your_Component)
- [How To Use Content Tags in Joomla!](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aHow_To_Use_Content_Tags_in_Joomla!)

Answer (score 2):

Migrating component from 2.x into 3.x

refer this link,

step 1: [Difference between 2.x into 3.x](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_3_FAQ)

step 2: [Important methods](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JRequest)