# What do I need to change in my 2.5 component, in order to work in 3.6?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a component that is compatible with joomla 2.5, but that is not rendering in a 3.6 enviroment (blank page).

What do I need to modify in order to make it work...?

Comment: In the `configuration.php` set **error_reporting** to `development`. The see this: https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

Comment: Thank you! Is there any log file attatched to this feature or just plain text on page?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question here on JSE:
[Q: Migrating component from 2.5 to 3.3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/694/migrating-component-from-2-5-to-3-3)
whose answers suggest two main links for information about J3 backwards compatibility and new API:
1. [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JRequest)
2. [Joomla 3.6. API](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check with the component(s) developer(s) to see if they have a version that is compatible with Joomla 3.x A lot of the top developers for Joomla will have versions compatible with the different versions of Joomla